# AT32UC3B0512 project compiled as AT32UC3B0256 -> Consequences

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, avrdude, winavr

I just figured out that I have compiled and programmed my AT32UC3B0512 project using the AT32UC3B0256 as target device.

My application seams to work without problems. Is that possible? What are the differences between AT32UC3B0512 and AT32UC3B0256 (beside flash and ram size)?

Comment: Looking (quickly) at the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32059.pdf) they seem hw compatible, but not in memory dimension (as you say) and the B0512 has a DAC, but the B0256 doesn't have it ...  I think the code may run good!

Answer (score 0):

in most cases the program EEPROM is the only difference.

- You use lower target then you have
- so it just limits the size of your program more then you can use in real.
- The functionality is not affected at all (tested for quite some time on L0,A0,and A3 series).

The only thing you have to be careful with UC3 chips are the pin incompatibility between package and series

- for example TQFP is much different then BGA ...
- also the same package with different pin count is incompatible
- also you can not change UC3A0 for UC3A3 ...
- the last 2/3 digits are only the EEPROM size
- and mostly does not affect SW/HW compatibility

[Note]

@SergioFormiggini is right the AT32UC3B0256 does not have DAC

- it is the first time I see a difference in HW config of a chip with different memory size only on Atmel chips
- Unless they also changed the memory map and or GPIO mappings you should be fine